# Finding the maximum entry based on another column in a data frame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose I have a data frame with 3 columns: `A, B, C`. I want to group by column `A`, and find the row (for each unique A) with the maximum entry in `C`, so that I can store that `row.A, row.B, row.C` into a dictionary elsewhere.

What's the best way to do this without using `iterrows`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# generate sample data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10,3)))
df.columns = ['A','B','C']

# sort by C, group by A, take last row of each group
df.sort('C').groupby('A').nth(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method.  If `df` is the DataFrame, you can write `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda d: d.ix[d['C'].argmax()])`.
For example,

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
    A  B  C
0   1  0  3
1   3  0  4
2   0  4  5
3   2  4  0
4   3  1  1
5   1  6  2
6   3  6  0
7   4  0  1
8   2  3  4
9   0  5  0
10  7  6  5
11  3  1  2

In [97]: g = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda d: d['C'].argmax())

In [98]: g
Out[98]: 
A
0     2
1     0
2     8
3     1
4     7
7    10
dtype: int64

In [99]: df.ix[g.values]
Out[99]: 
    A  B  C
2   0  4  5
0   1  0  3
8   2  3  4
1   3  0  4
7   4  0  1
10  7  6  5
```